# Ubuntu ISO download issue

Tags: iso

I downloaded the Ubuntu 'ISO Image' however when the download finished it was a .RAR file ? Why did I not get the ISO image I want ? Also after opening the.RAR file there was the ISO image to be found inside. I need the image to create a bootable USB stick so I can dual-boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exact link did you download from?

Comment: Here ya go...https://www.ubuntu.com/download

Answer (score 3):

Just because it was opened with winRAR, it doesn't mean it's a .rar file. WinRAR is able to open .iso files.
It's probably a .iso file as well, if you downloaded from the ubuntu official site.

sorry for any language mistakes.
Have a nice day :)